# Import all attributes and methods of a class into the current scope in python

Tags: python

I would like to import the attributes and methods from a locally defined instance of a class along the following lines:

```
from myClassInstance import *
```

One motivation: here is how ugly things get when I converted from a script to a class:

[image]

I would need to prefix all of those attributes and methods with the `hs.` it would seem..    But is there a way to import all of those attributes into the current namespace?  I am asking it were *possible* (not so interested if it were considered *pythonic* ..)

**Update** While an answer was selected/awarded below the bigger issue - that of converting a script to a *unit-testable* class - was not successful. The amount of refactoring is excessive for what is supposed to be a small task. I'll have to stick to a monolithic script at this point.  Maybe I will follow-up with a question on approaches to converting a script monolith to a unit-testable class-based approach without the hair-pulling.

Comment: please use code layout instead of images.

Comment: @DivyanshuSrivastava I did it this way to show the impact of how many places are affected (the _red_ ...)

Comment: Python doesn't even have an implicit `this` pointer in methods - that's a design choice (and as far as I'm concerned a very sensible one) -, so obviously it won't support such a "feature".

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might consider an alternative design where HamSpam is a module rather than a class. Then the `import *` mechanism will work perfectly well.

Comment: @Kevin that actually _is_ a worthwhile answer (and feel free to add it as such): providing an approach that addresses the sense of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a very bad hack and you should never do this.

You can emulate `import` from an object like this. But please don't

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def method1(self):
        print(1)

    def method2(self):
        print(2)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = SomeClass()
    for a in dir(s):
        if callable(getattr(s, a)):
            globals()[a] = getattr(s, a)
    method1()
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: You added the obligatory "hack" .. "never do this" so as to not get creamed by pythonistas..

Comment: This is definitely not something sane you would want to put in production. But just wanted to show that it is possible. Python gives you all the tools.

Comment: I tried to convert a script to a class _for the purpose of adding unit tests_ and then everything broke left right up and down and need to do an inordinate amount of refactoring. Having unit tests _is_ the essence of being prepared for production but then making the conversion becomes so costly that I hesitate. I can assure you I am not alone in wanting to keep code in scripts instead of classes due to the large overhead and lower readability: I work with persons who only do python regularly and see relatively few _classes_ in their code but instead monolithic scripts.

Comment: This does get the job done but the IDE does not know about the dynamically imported scope so it marks everything red still.

Comment: Since the methods are injected into the global scope at runtime IDE won't know about them